# Dropdown value coming blank but still going in IF condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

While submitting a form, I am not selecting any value from the dropdownlist and I am checking condition as

```
if (Request.Form["CmbNextUser"] != Session["UserId"].ToString() || Request.Form["CmbNextUser"] != null || Request.Form["CmbNextUser"] != "")
        {
            TransferMail();
        }
```

So, while debugging my value comes as like below.

[image: IMG]

The value is coming blank but still it is going in the **IF** condition

Comment: You have 3 conditions. If any of them evaluates to `true`, it'll get triggered.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: my first condition comes to true, I guess I need to write **AND** instead of **OR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Condition one is causing for this since you are comparing value

   ```
    Request.Form["CmbNextUser"] != Session["UserId"].ToString()
   ```

   i.e `"" != Session["UserId"].ToString()`  which is evaluated as ture
   thats why it it executing if block.
2. Change code like this

   ```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["CmbNextUser"]) || Request.Form["CmbNextUser"] != Session["UserId"].ToString() )
   {
       TransferMail();
   }
   ```

Comment: no, that's not the issue. I shd have checked with AND instead of OR

Comment: have you made changes like above and tested it? this will definitely not going to execute if block when the value is empty

Comment: but you have added only one condition. I need to check for all the 3 conditions

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty` this will check both your condition

Answer (score 0):

Your IF conditions have logical **OR**s between them. This means if **any one** of them are met, the whole thing will execute. Did you mean to use *&&* (and) instead of *||* (or).